# Accessing Ember local server from another browser

Tags: ember.js

I have set up an Ember app in a VM in the cloud and I would like to access it from my local browser. I found that for django can do something like:

> python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000

Is there something similar that I can do with "ember serve" command?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can set the **host** value in an `.ember-cli` file in the root of your project.

See http://ember-cli.com/#runtime-configuration

```
# ~/.ember-cli
{
  "skipGit" : true,
  "port" : 999,
  "host" : "0.1.0.1",
  "liveReload" : true,
  "environment" : "mock-development",
  "checkForUpdates" : false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`./node_modules/ember-cli/bin/ember s --watcher=node host="0.0.0.0" --port=8000` 
Thats what I do.

I'm utilizing the ember bin file from `node_modules` instead of the global one you do in general `npm install -g ember-cli`